# Error : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got the Error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond **.**.**.***:25

when I sending the mail on the server.

I tried this solution but I still got the same error.

The problem was that the line
`IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(ipStr);` of the server program should have been `IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Any;`

Here, I created one function to send mail.

```
private static void SetUserCredentialAndProcessMail(MailMessage msg, string mailTo)
{
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(SendMail.userName, SendMail.password);
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SendMail.smtpServer, SendMail.SmtpPort);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = SendMail.testMode == "1";
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpClient.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost)networkCredential;
    try
    {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(SendMail.mailFrom, mailTo, msg.Subject, msg.Body);
            message.IsBodyHtml = msg.IsBodyHtml;
            if (msg.Attachments != null && msg.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Attachment attachment in (Collection<Attachment>)msg.Attachments)
                    message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
            smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

What could be the reasons for such an error..???

Comment: Have you checked if your connectioninfo are all correct? Host, user, etc? Other possible option - often - is that a firewall is blocking the response from the server?

Comment: The error is clear and explains what happened - the server didn't respond in time. If the server is slow, you may have to increase the timeout. Or it could be a wrong IP/port. Finally, almost all SMTP servers require TLS-encrypted connections. Are you *sure* the IP is correct and the server doesn't require encryption? The server may simply refuse to respond to attempts to connect over a wrong port

Comment: Are you trying to connect to GMail, Yahoo or any other hosted SMTP server? Those always required encrypted connections. Have you tried to `telnet` to that IP/Port? An SMTP session is little more than connecting to the IP and typing specific text commands. You can send an email through TELNET. If you can't connect that way, you can't send an email through any other client